# How to do calculate columns sum?

Tags: c#, sum, devexpress, hour, gridcontrol

The columns in the GridControl prepared by the showfooter method there are hours like you see in the picture I want to sum the columns of those hours how do I do it?

Thnx for your help

[image]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TimeSpan` class to parse strings in the format `hours:minutes`, and can add them together in a loop. For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var colTimes = new List<string>
    {
        "01:00", "02:10", "07:40", "03:45", "02:45"
    };

    var totalTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

    foreach(string colTime in colTimes)
    {
        totalTime = totalTime.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(colTime));
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Times: {string.Join(", ", colTimes)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"\nThe total is: {totalTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm")}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
}
```

Or you could do a Linq-based alternative and avoid the loop:

```
var totalTime = new TimeSpan(colTimes.Sum(time => TimeSpan.Parse(time).Ticks));
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: How do I implement this code for the WinForm platform?

Comment: It would help if you could  update your question to show the code you currently have that calculates the other totals.